# Liquibase Unknown change type 'loadData'

Tags: spring-boot, jhipster, liquibase

I have been using JHipster for a long time.

But suddenly, I faced this stupid exception, and I couldn't find any solution for it.

I have exactly one other project that works without any problem, but in this project Liquibase says that it does not recognize the `loadData` change type.

```
liquibase.parser.core.ParsedNodeException: Error parsing config/liquibase/changelog/00000000000000_initial_schema.xml: Unknown change type 'loadData'. Check for spelling or capitalization errors and missing extensions such as liquibase-commercial.
```

I would appreciate any help

Full Stacktrace:

```
2022-10-19T13:19:45.872+02:00 ERROR 182498 --- [all-club-task-1] t.j.c.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase     : Liquibase could not start correctly, your database is NOT ready: liquibase.exception.SetupException: liquibase.parser.core.ParsedNodeException: Error parsing config/liquibase/changelog/00000000000000_initial_schema.xml: Unknown change type 'loadData'. Check for spelling or capitalization errors and missing extensions such as liquibase-commercial. 

liquibase.exception.ChangeLogParseException: liquibase.exception.SetupException: liquibase.parser.core.ParsedNodeException: Error parsing config/liquibase/changelog/00000000000000_initial_schema.xml: Unknown change type 'loadData'. Check for spelling or capitalization errors and missing extensions such as liquibase-commercial.
    at liquibase.parser.core.xml.AbstractChangeLogParser.parse(AbstractChangeLogParser.java:25)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.getDatabaseChangeLog(Liquibase.java:380)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.getDatabaseChangeLog(Liquibase.java:365)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.lambda$update$1(Liquibase.java:222)
    at liquibase.Scope.lambda$child$0(Scope.java:180)
    at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:189)
    at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:179)
    at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:158)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.runInScope(Liquibase.java:2414)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:209)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:195)
    at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.performUpdate(SpringLiquibase.java:314)
    at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(SpringLiquibase.java:269)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.liquibase.DataSourceClosingSpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(DataSourceClosingSpringLiquibase.java:46)
    at tech.jhipster.config.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase.initDb(AsyncSpringLiquibase.java:118)
    at tech.jhipster.config.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$0(AsyncSpringLiquibase.java:93)
    at tech.jhipster.async.ExceptionHandlingAsyncTaskExecutor.lambda$createWrappedRunnable$1(ExceptionHandlingAsyncTaskExecutor.java:79)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: liquibase.exception.SetupException: liquibase.parser.core.ParsedNodeException: Error parsing config/liquibase/changelog/00000000000000_initial_schema.xml: Unknown change type 'loadData'. Check for spelling or capitalization errors and missing extensions such as liquibase-commercial.
    at liquibase.changelog.DatabaseChangeLog.handleChildNode(DatabaseChangeLog.java:391)
    at liquibase.changelog.DatabaseChangeLog.load(DatabaseChangeLog.java:339)
    at liquibase.parser.core.xml.AbstractChangeLogParser.parse(AbstractChangeLogParser.java:23)
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: liquibase.exception.ChangeLogParseException: liquibase.parser.core.ParsedNodeException: Error parsing config/liquibase/changelog/00000000000000_initial_schema.xml: Unknown change type 'loadData'. Check for spelling or capitalization errors and missing extensions such as liquibase-commercial.
    at liquibase.parser.core.xml.AbstractChangeLogParser.parse(AbstractChangeLogParser.java:25)
    at liquibase.changelog.DatabaseChangeLog.include(DatabaseChangeLog.java:671)
    at liquibase.changelog.DatabaseChangeLog.handleChildNode(DatabaseChangeLog.java:383)
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: liquibase.parser.core.ParsedNodeException: Error parsing config/liquibase/changelog/00000000000000_initial_schema.xml: Unknown change type 'loadData'. Check for spelling or capitalization errors and missing extensions such as liquibase-commercial.
    at liquibase.changelog.ChangeSet.toChange(ChangeSet.java:525)
    at liquibase.changelog.ChangeSet.handleChildNode(ChangeSet.java:454)
    at liquibase.changelog.ChangeSet.load(ChangeSet.java:382)
    at liquibase.changelog.DatabaseChangeLog.createChangeSet(DatabaseChangeLog.java:715)
    at liquibase.changelog.DatabaseChangeLog.handleChildNode(DatabaseChangeLog.java:370)
    at liquibase.changelog.DatabaseChangeLog.load(DatabaseChangeLog.java:339)
    at liquibase.parser.core.xml.AbstractChangeLogParser.parse(AbstractChangeLogParser.java:23)
    ... 23 common frames omitted
```

My databaseChangeLog file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<databaseChangeLog
    xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
    xmlns:ext="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-latest.xsd
                        http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-ext.xsd">

    <changeSet id="00000000000000" author="jhipster">
        <createSequence sequenceName="sequence_generator" startValue="1050" incrementBy="50"/>
    </changeSet>

    <!--
        JHipster core tables.
        The initial schema has the '00000000000001' id, so that it is over-written if we re-generate it.
    -->
    <changeSet id="00000000000001" author="jhipster">
        <createTable tableName="jhi_user">
            <column name="id" type="${uuidType}">
                <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false"/>
            </column>
            <column name="login" type="varchar(50)">
                <constraints unique="true" nullable="false" uniqueConstraintName="ux_user_login"/>
            </column>
            <column name="password_hash" type="varchar(60)"/>
            <column name="email" type="varchar(191)">
                <constraints unique="true" nullable="true" uniqueConstraintName="ux_user_email"/>
            </column>
            <column name="image_url" type="varchar(256)"/>
            <column name="activated" type="boolean" valueBoolean="false">
                <constraints nullable="false" />
            </column>
            <column name="lang_key" type="varchar(10)"/>
            <column name="activation_key" type="varchar(20)"/>
            <column name="reset_key" type="varchar(20)"/>
            <column name="created_by" type="varchar(50)">
                <constraints nullable="false"/>
            </column>
            <column name="created_date" type="timestamp"/>
            <column name="reset_date" type="timestamp">
                <constraints nullable="true"/>
            </column>
            <column name="last_modified_by" type="varchar(50)"/>
            <column name="last_modified_date" type="timestamp"/>
        </createTable>

        <createTable tableName="jhi_authority">
            <column name="name" type="varchar(50)">
                <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false"/>
            </column>
        </createTable>

        <createTable tableName="jhi_user_authority">
            <column name="user_id" type="${uuidType}">
                <constraints nullable="false"/>
            </column>
            <column name="authority_name" type="varchar(50)">
                <constraints nullable="false"/>
            </column>
        </createTable>

        <addPrimaryKey columnNames="user_id, authority_name" tableName="jhi_user_authority"/>

        <addForeignKeyConstraint baseColumnNames="authority_name"
                                 baseTableName="jhi_user_authority"
                                 constraintName="fk_authority_name"
                                 referencedColumnNames="name"
                                 referencedTableName="jhi_authority"/>

        <addForeignKeyConstraint baseColumnNames="user_id"
                                 baseTableName="jhi_user_authority"
                                 constraintName="fk_user_id"
                                 referencedColumnNames="id"
                                 referencedTableName="jhi_user"/>

        <addNotNullConstraint   columnName="password_hash"
                                columnDataType="varchar(60)"
                                tableName="jhi_user"/>
        <loadData
            file="config/liquibase/data/user.csv"
            separator=";"
            tableName="jhi_user"
            usePreparedStatements="true">
            <column name="id" type="${uuidType}"/>
            <column name="activated" type="boolean"/>
            <column name="created_date" type="timestamp"/>
        </loadData>
        <dropDefaultValue tableName="jhi_user" columnName="created_date" columnDataType="${datetimeType}"/>
        <loadData
            file="config/liquibase/data/authority.csv"
            separator=";"
            tableName="jhi_authority"
            usePreparedStatements="true">
            <column name="name" type="string"/>
        </loadData>
        <loadData
            file="config/liquibase/data/user_authority.csv"
            separator=";"
            tableName="jhi_user_authority"
            usePreparedStatements="true">
            <column name="user_id" type="${uuidType}"/>
        </loadData>
    </changeSet>

    <changeSet author="jhipster" id="00000000000002" context="test">
        <createTable tableName="jhi_date_time_wrapper">
            <column  name="id" type="BIGINT">
                <constraints primaryKey="true" primaryKeyName="jhi_date_time_wrapperPK"/>
            </column>
            <column name="instant" type="timestamp"/>
            <column name="local_date_time" type="timestamp"/>
            <column name="offset_date_time" type="timestamp"/>
            <column name="zoned_date_time" type="timestamp"/>
            <column name="local_time" type="time"/>
            <column name="offset_time" type="time"/>
            <column name="local_date" type="date"/>
        </createTable>
    </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

Answer (score 0):

I spoke with @nvoxland about this yesterday, and he said that he answered a very similar question on the [Liquibase forum](https://forum.liquibase.org/t/loaddata-not-recognised-using-gradle-plugin/7364).

The short version: you need to update to the most current Liquibase release and then try again. If that doesn't work, then you should add open.csv to the dependency.

Answer (score 0):

I got same error I think its depends on the opencsv version. With opencsv 5.6 i resolved this promlem.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
            <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
            <version>5.6</version>
</dependency>
```